# PostGres/RaspberryPI Restart-always-needed

Tags: postgresql, raspberry-pi4

Why does postgresql systematically need to be restarted ?

I have installed PostGres on a RaspberryPI and it is working; but something is weird.

Here is the status of the postgresql service after booting the RaspberryPI.

```
 root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# systemctl status postgresql
 ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
      Active: active (exited) since Sun 2023-12-10 09:18:30 GMT; 5h 4min ago
     Process: 743 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Main PID: 743 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         CPU: 2ms

 Dec 10 09:18:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS...
 Dec 10 09:18:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Finished postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS.
 root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

Then I run a program on a computer (Linux-Debian) on the same LAN, which accesses the DB on the PI.

It always fails the first time and gets a connection refusal.

Then on the RaspberryPI (PostGres server), I restart the postgresql service:

```
 root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# systemctl restart postgresql
 root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# 
 root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# systemctl status postgresql
 ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
      Active: active (exited) since Sun 2023-12-10 14:23:14 GMT; 11s ago
     Process: 918 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Main PID: 918 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         CPU: 2ms

 Dec 10 14:23:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS...
 Dec 10 14:23:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Finished postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS.
 root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

At this point the program on the Linux-Debian computer can connect and works normally.

It is no big deal but a bit annoying. Can someone think of a possible explanation and solution ?

Just in case this may be useful:

```
% psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 15.1
%
```

Comment: From this, how can anyone tell. What is in the logs?

Comment: My experience with postgres is limited, I thought some expert would have an idea. Anyway how can I get the logs you are referring to ?

Comment: journalctl + /var/log/postgresql